# SVG with Base64 is not rendered properly in HTML 5 canvas in Edge in some scenarios

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, microsoft-edge

I want to generate an image of the DOM element containing base64 images. For the same, I am converting the DOM element to SVG and then drawing that SVG on the canvas and obtaining base64 from it.

It is observed that HTML element having a smaller image is rendered properly, while that having larger image isn't rendered in the canvas in **Edge**.

Here is a snippet for the same:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content1">
      <img id="smallImg" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApkZXNjAAAA/AAAAF5jcHJ0AAABXAAAAAt3dHB0AAABaAAAABRia3B0AAABfAAAABRyWFlaAAABkAAAABRnWFlaAAABpAAAABRiWFlaAAABuAAAABRyVFJDAAABzAAAAEBnVFJDAAABzAAAAEBiVFJDAAABzAAAAEBkZXNjAAAAAAAAAANjMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB0ZXh0AAAAAElYAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLVhZWiAAAAAAAAADFgAAAzMAAAKkWFlaIAAAAAAAAG+iAAA49QAAA5BYWVogAAAAAAAAYpkAALeFAAAY2lhZWiAAAAAAAAAkoAAAD4QAALbPY3VydgAAAAAAAAAaAAAAywHJA2MFkghrC/YQPxVRGzQh8SmQMhg7kkYFUXdd7WtwegWJsZp8rGm/fdPD6TD////bAIQABQYGBwkHCgsLCg0ODQ4NExIQEBITHRUWFRYVHSsbIBsbIBsrJi4mIyYuJkQ2MDA2RE9CP0JPX1VVX3hyeJyc0gEFBgYHCQcKCwsKDQ4NDg0TEhAQEhMdFRYVFhUdKxsgGxsgGysmLiYjJi4mRDYwMDZET0I/Qk9fVVVfeHJ4nJzS/8IAEQgAlgDIAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EABwAAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQIDBgcBCP/aAAgBAQAAAAD86gAAAAAAAAAAAAAZW/QwJvKxMAAdX+q/ypy2239epegpt9VRcCAD279EeWeJQvRZ/PyI2cvXA8rwANvt1jq4zLO35/djnnt18nzAAupNZ19lmgRo8Wbaz4fnMYAHQ2O6VP5dJkYzbzzOqACR3s7DlcZvO3UWxt93mmIAJ3R6sYOiTAr7ronE6gAS5tvDlUG3ZJsrKl5UADdnvvY8OHLuvnQedwgALP07zXCVaI9j9l+eawAL/PnpWV7Bu7jjKMAA+2XW50Pzpe9tfB+cAAHadP8AKTmbLve08E54AAej3vLT6DX21BweIAA9Lj89a7K6876N4IA//8QAGgEBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDBAUBBv/aAAgBAhAAAACIAAPIpgcOzdme27QfK9HyRLoXA5+CyU6tu4FfCs0s3U0g8wYJPe36D2HKru6UwCnHp0gEqPn+v0Ij/8QAHAEBAAEFAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMBAgUGBwQI/9oACAEDEAAAAMYAAD05WLD0BsmudI7B7LObcXoLsvN9A5WO+nz9poOj9mhw9uwcs5KDJ/Q1dai3TiGlAm3vqV09PmuAFLulZG3mHkARUui9FQEFLI/ZeP/EACoQAAICAQQBBAEEAwEAAAAAAAECAwQRAAUSEyEGIjAxMhQjJEAHFUFg/9oACAEBAAEMAP8AyvFuOcHG17W913UOEDei73QsiyxE7fsEr2GWyrRix6bDXWEbcIZ6ciWpIFBdnR0YqylW+T0zsb7ldCdZdKv+OqtjaBBZhqGH1V6as7Hub1ZWDqVYfakahrzTNxjRnNbZbLWoop0eJRGkcCRrgxx1ateTESBF7eqT7BV3Ms335GOQzqrVWJnZfLbhsli1Ymm5oh+T0Deq0Y1klhjkLb/WkqFq+Y5N3Xbt4tI5sSxyeq9sFGdY13CSwPTlnqsSDONC2JExkZfrHJV1Zk9+llDQkZ8wvh11JNlsZ0CAM50JkOR/xqO3cWMkEeHKl24ghfhi4di8vxpPsskaPEJInvzxx1v49kF/T/qFWrdorK49e76u4Wq6r+ENLabMMUqRNEWrsnlZORMyywIc4Z5XaQg/crNFI8bHzFOF950JkXLHyS7OcltB1Q4+zbgNqu0YYobuxdFd5VnD/HBusiIFdFfVnf7UkJiXCJSstG5HJgKNShHGH4Bz2IowgUKDHIMM2D7ouSMPI/cmU51uUwY9gPmTsCo2Dwaxyk+/EdsZxnUU0B/4xMZ8+3W47bPZj4pZVVs1pa8zRSDDfJRsEJjmMiXkfb9usypllIEFwSp0yHy1av1jhI6yN2I7Iy5LbrJG/WUBFe3BXiD8C2oqteyjPBkydEsIBdCBDMc+M6ru7/n+O7GM7hOUkLr8dfq7l7PwiWqF5FQBXdWy/XhJ0eZeTE8bUQQ+FYaXcpggDAkXbO3LLJFKzg1bUDpiRS2qzGP3IwfUt5VttJEoU1rZSMKe1dRIUHILyFlhNUmVOQkIIJBGD8i3rAULz8C7OqEL7kqzWpp1RJHXVuxcEoiEpJ3XIc+fF+ZpKtNpTzNjaZqsQnglWSFLII5cVDSAuSTjFONyQSc6qvGh8xE63K6tdEaJcNLK8kjOxy3yVoRIxz+LSlfC+Bs1g9k5C+Y2AsrM+SL/AOmEqyiRZFedbE8arEI0qQwzW3rCUrGKclb2SwIuoK0iFgoRwkcZwykkRQyqQxw677TjHGwh8fLHM6Zx9cpJScDSMyAsjEariGPbY3fQq8Y4i2ObKK8IIUmUUexImA8VZZTiCRiyIDHKqlRxhWerO2hamHt4odXLc1iVnkPzbbt8lyysS+Aau3165g4DhbtRu7MNI8k0tdHbwJpFuQvIfG7oiqQPLbaYhUVDgM1UMEmhOksQFuDjg6Xqki8XlAaSzTWrz7Q2pXDSOwGPm2O60FlgGC63qw5mMYJ4j7GmJCxuje6ZZHcM7E6pNBJAkbMAwP78scg4ioJK/hhlP9DdtwLaij5JvNKavOpkQqf6EUc12ZVP3X2enGoJUu1qCF04lfG4ivGsXtcarNRk3CHgHCXaVKWTlFKja2vb6S7dDXco7bibdDZAlCDm+67/ALheTrtcCf6GwL/Hk8DRXI/LQ6ozkDnJuYkmib2gybfVKSuWOqy/udmtnnJOTwIfeErRNIXiQb9vT7lbEpjRB/Q9Oxq9DOPLx4+vu9u0UDgJh3rzJPxaMgizDPDNMw/FpAZOCfVR0WMJHxLbrt2+SBgF5RMrKxVgQf6HpZT+gkOr7WppnTt4RNSgHgLnW10ov1CMCVaSdJjc7GdgWHYWCqutvkYNqm2ca9T7GL1BpUKLJ8H/xAAwEAEAAQMDAwIFBAEFAQAAAAABEQACITFBUQMSYTBxIjKBkaEQQLHB0RNgcnPh8P/aAAgBAQANPwD/AGrzGKtNUkl0KTNrIjxP91Ywmiv+KgR1zuFW3IQZaGEcI+qa2950y54bnSrSbey+67qdH/r6qv2SGk7ul1DS+x0fDyV5IrgJrqT8UToTii0AQjGzyNXQoc/WnFTAvFGa6l7ddduz/VR8NrrdBu7T6vdI3W5sbt/JtNBLY5tuOKt6fZ0/9PonVSWVJgHbmlVs6vTu6fUseW1wjyVdZ/DQintxUSHjxUFGamt655p1rtZxEHOKlgeNvSnNQF/xd2fZ2otWAjBmpy6Nq6zXStfgWUXXJs8Uk23dO6H2Z1o8Q0YHh/TFGAp0H+a2rnalJQmTiKtJbW2GPTtIF1DjzSZAD+Ku1hj71dnuuO6PFcW4jyVtdt9ajPk5Kt1eSoJpDJ/f6btczXNa9ra592rXPq75rxW1HyXblduS+EXwlbDpFRnt4eEpxET96DubNBN09qdHb715r8134uf4+nqTmtgNat0NlrYKN65aZ7GMGMM1p3RCRvJX3tu8PFJPaYEcRneki4bpK5pt+EmCaNT1TxtSYrLq4ClD6tWnaeY3+tWfDdY5YGX8Vcd1vJb59qdLghfEVbBAbzrXmvermIucVcy+qZf8VxR0sfVqzqEh41ihHtHL48V3QpluXzT07s90HcZ/FXGL5UzuJVts3FjmHM0gjueKeDP2q5LbrdM8nrOpRrGxy1HbJiaW5jlnSutcv/3tXxQuls7+/FXGvmrWbR280h23GtryNTnhmkm3ES1Py7Hra3PBQF16vzRvdSsAQFZLTYKtuLQ4HFfwUSniNVq1w+1QPNvucVbNs3ESbfarY+RF14puWPf1upb2y7b1Avn3/S3ONmaYy0XdobsuIpu7f+KY+1XMXeOGhbUPmI3Dcq+2ckSmH9iAXXcHLXN2n0KGcYq1zjUqBW35jzVx8fxZnn35oukT4suY/wDK6ctu6Cyvlq26R7Yutjb/AD+xeph3wfpsOh5eadFJ+1PTw8JrV0i0WxaXMRw1aS90se0VaIdpE5mXy/sS+4n81tUxcbB780/hoy40LsL+aX8c/WkhE/ujS2xFT21o1EhP2L1n+KNrfmunlrlaGRtYrpqWiGSdGnYqP06A39yfNaGRT8ej/8QAKxEAAQMCBQIEBwAAAAAAAAAAAQACEQMSBCAhMUFRYQUwMpEiQIGhscHh/9oACAECAQE/APkiQBJRqNAmU17TsfIx/iNOiHgnVrSROknsV4Zja2IoU3PaAY+LVVK9ri2OE4mN04zC4IH1TK8aH7Z8T4ZiatUSQWh3MbJlEYeoTcbeG/1Ofcfwidldqr0DBBHCovLhqRPbPjHCA2D1lBqa4bFWkHfRAadkY4WEHqM9s9Sy0lwBATTJ5hAyN+U3XRTGyMysM1lgIiTuc5aHCCJCxNFwta0COg/a0lAnaVcrKnAKaAANIzyVwQqmHLToRHEp1FwbIE9VTwrneraPYqm21gEzA8kgp7RBO6NcWiOqovOw9/KcdAnbqkSKz46qgSjxl//EADERAAIBAwMCBAQEBwAAAAAAAAECAwAEERIhMQVBBiAiMhMwUXEHYYGhFCMkQFKxwf/aAAgBAwEBPwD+ytrWe4mWKJCztnAHfG9ReH+qSTxxfw7qz8E7Dbc5Par7ol/aAGWIhTIUU/5EfQc4ogg4PPnNtHHBGugamUFmIzud8U2NTAcA14e8KW19ZxXDStn4mGTthTuPruKhtINSMI1DIuFbAyAfpSRAZPfGM09tE0iOygsgOk/TPNdd8FCeQzW8ioxLNIXJ9RJz24ojBO+fKrYYHAODnBq5vxKnJyex3/eui9Dm6jIyxyIukZYt2H/asOnw26ZVFV2UfE0bKWA5ArgDFfFIyD25pJ0JO9XMEdxA8TglHUqwBxkH7V4q6QlndAw20kcBGkMxyGbnbn9/P4IsnaeSdZIxpGnSfdvvn7VFG2N2yfyGBTzBT6s7fSrm+IkEaSoCc53327U/UEQrqwM7AY3/AEqCTK5FfiDdN/TQ/DOnd9edieMefpjXxuVjtZHV5Dp9LFc/fHaopyxjVm32yBxnvipfWkmWxnjJ4FSGL4jMBknCI2dJyBz9jRspJdIk/UYOx/arWIxxqBk/nz/uvGF5ev1KSKUkRoQY0zkYI936+eGeWGQPG5RhwQcGvDvU4dVxPczHWB72bt2CiklDxodOAoVd/sMk1JZRNPoIBXRt96ggCKAzd/SSc5H0zS9QsVibF1EAoJOHBIA5q4leSZ3dy7FiSx5P5/IRgrA7HBzirPxZbtGomVg5ODp9ox3q38YQS3cUb/y4gnuYd+2rHbFX/jeIRlII9TLLj1bqVB5BGOavbkXF1LNoCa3LaQc4z8liM0cjBovkZoHJ5+Ufcaycc13o80nt8v8A/9k=">
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
      <img id="bigImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApkZXNjAAAA/AAAAF5jcHJ0AAABXAAAAAt3dHB0AAABaAAAABRia3B0AAABfAAAABRyWFlaAAABkAAAABRnWFlaAAABpAAAABRiWFlaAAABuAAAABRyVFJDAAABzAAAAEBnVFJDAAABzAAAAEBiVFJDAAABzAAAAEBkZXNjAAAAAAAAAANjMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB0ZXh0AAAAAElYAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLVhZWiAAAAAAAAADFgAAAzMAAAKkWFlaIAAAAAAAAG+iAAA49QAAA5BYWVogAAAAAAAAYpkAALeFAAAY2lhZWiAAAAAAAAAkoAAAD4QAALbPY3VydgAAAAAAAAAaAAAAywHJA2MFkghrC/YQPxVRGzQh8SmQMhg7kkYFUXdd7WtwegWJsZp8rGm/fdPD6TD////bAIQABQYGBwkHCgsLCg0ODQ4NExIQEBITHRUWFRYVHSsbIBsbIBsrJi4mIyYuJkQ2MDA2RE9CP0JPX1VVX3hyeJyc0gEFBgYHCQcKCwsKDQ4NDg0TEhAQEhMdFRYVFhUdKxsgGxsgGysmLiYjJi4mRDYwMDZET0I/Qk9fVVVfeHJ4nJzS/8IAEQgBXgHTAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EABwAAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQMGBwIBCP/aAAgBAQAAAAD86gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+39PHAAAAAAAAPfWPXjRpnSNLttP1gAAAAAOx6BrYBsnQ9Xpej3FpF1CZnx88vb/jAAAAAE/uHYdl/IHOQfbDskrHD8W+D7TZsuWil+NIqqwAAAAOh/rHfJeg/hK4i0Pvp1pTbfIhwIuwQ4OG2jesPvK1rm/kAAAAyfozvGzaLg4dpvOcfvslh4l+4ddAnTKj7YY4szN5+esfrkcAAAACw6tt272PNre64TzF0WxtLSL8qIUiyq02H8tkLzn9xuSeQAAAfen3c27q8/Qbz8/8323X7iTsMyng4MsmKtqmwQvsqZ65zrvwAAAHrpPSJ87muq7vccdouuz66sxbJU0GebDxzPGXH6zZ4/nP7UnPwAAAXu1TrnX+cdN1WmvNmlfIXi0w1HjYtPz5sOSNPz5cWfPNwUnPAAAALSXirMFpsOze42P1PqpHiv8AdhrLDni+pvuzm5fnzPqWswAAAAA+3u14fvr56vK2LDsq2Hh2Gjr7SrzSZVnnsZP2PxsAAAAGXY5vrD69eNrpNg12hl5fTJfV1bEky5UiVOr+UgAAAAyXEz5Mm4a1tMjLqtTM1iXsVLZbrVYq/LOmWdbywAAAAPe3z5siRl1uthfNix5YGvTcfvY8NLZWPjHbTI3LsQAAAAS90s8US8r5NTRV+P3uVfq/m2lYokP7eTZ3mTZcmwAAAAAt9mi32Sv9+4tV41/e+YYbay+zqujvZMuztYUqv0MAAAABazvcX5dUMn1r97S7ZrcCfKqMGe0uZdvP1DVcQAAAAD3tMeJsFtomwwtdsYUnoPL8EmLZe7Gz+5moQgAAAAC7+4/u5U+u7zR4ZmmWdfnyWFbNu8GbFf5OYeAAAAAFjZQY8fdq3Dlt9UopGyaX2bVqm1l11tktI8vVtSAAAAATZ8SHksa7d6ylkwLOphYtt+e7Oq97bN+6zo+IAAAAAM0jLE6do2xUvqvrbPzV7HPq72mtJOTnfwAAAAANxmVVVLmV9zDtaKh6FV0U7YMFxX4raFo8IAAAAAdD3yHziqq8l5VW2261rvQo0Ojvbiqv4k+DzuGAAAAAX3X9dpdDxSfO0V1VvWv19smz4NBMqJljV1IAAAAAu9717TPKX9w/cWw3FfVyvu3eNSsdTxAAAAAAfeh6xRGadDnRvmzfdX2WbG2PoGo871oAAAAABMsaKRsd01a41m4qOh6tD7Listz0PVuRAAAAAADZtyyYYeCPql1XdiqIPUMtho35++AAAAAAC13/ACo0a6qNM1+/toO0bRsex2OrcF10AAAAAA2Ldfb1YUuPTaPZPvy+m7vdfdF5DGAAAAAANr23IQZUKPr86ttvF7t/ur4xhAAAAAAG+7Zh+R4WLL91qFaxM+85dM1KIAAAAAAG+bvjjVehwtzuYdHFg7Df2WWm0qhAAAAAAG6dCg6ZrWbx92ixrocKwl7HdWVrz7jwAAAAABvm+abXZImKVtmn7HqX31OvdhtredwjRwAAP//EABsBAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwEEBQYH/9oACAECEAAAAIgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACMgAAIyCqiVdV114AA1ubX1NummiGxTKdO1tgAMeY85D6NscO+yi2FmM1462QAank+D6Hr9LUqvqkmilu3gAh53HYprpsnDOGJyjd0gABxtSVl2K7I2VJZ6GyAAcjXzGexVCyea63YtAAY4ddk687cMWw10OzcAAOVo2ZbFtcq6G50gABDgRuStnKrFWN3ogACGnDQSlNjEJ9e0AALOTpwnGzEZwx3pAACSvU5ZjMod5YAACE6uXRZDGeltTAAAQnXpWWVb7AAABHEIxjRvSmAAAlnEKObG6/dkAAAnmqFfmd/bv27IgD/8QAHAEBAAEFAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMCBAUGBwEI/9oACAEDEAAAAMYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL6xAAAqpFzse5Zq227T9U56AAN1x+Agq3jcehXNvd+W3vKuSgALjd8JrtFX1PN7eUTU+eeY35diABsOTwGGl6Xv+z11e+qqmp8m0cAEuVsIugdH2imaGLxJPX5pHAIwADrXT6664aVpL7fTx8K58AAq7DvGT8hltNZv6r7IXUXzjrwACf6Cz92sMZY4PN4qPd8jH834IAAdg3u8x8GIuMHHd7lkOf8TpAAL3vE2Vi91e3yEt9nfebcbAAF5tl10XYcdbY33PU39fzjggAAp6Zt+Yry+Lu11XH8v2gAA8jvdo6sztnc5DWuFsQAADz2+6TmrKx3Cy5rq0IAACglkoyWFk9AAAeR+e03EUflU4AACmHyaGqqBc1gAAKbeXymKumOq6kAH/xABAEAACAgECAwYDBgQDBgcAAAABAgADEQQhEjFBBRMiUWFxMoGREBRAUFKhI0JisXLB0QYVJDDh8CAzQ3OAgpL/2gAIAQEAAT8B/wDl7RoLbM/yj1llbI3Cef5oASQBF0GmZFBTxY5iaTsikixbQc8XhYHpLewqgdrWHrjM1Wgvo3Iyv6hymhoyeM/KVgY3mv05ssr4RzBBMo0lVeNsnznaNKpaOEY4hnH5Jo+wtHrU4aNRYl/6LUwD7ETX9mavRWcF9ZXyPMH2P/K0GjF9hDEhRzxB2bo+H4M+5mq7JwvHSeIfpPOaOhxcCykY8xFO4nFj5GIwbIblM44lbfb6iYCjAGIDP5TF5ztDL6rhHkBKNDUnxeIy+pLKCmPb3/IKKTY4XIX1PITQa9qcVaOhOLq/DxE/5zT6XtmzxHWWKfJqBj+8s02oek062uu6s/zpnb3B3+YnbnYlugv/AFVMfA3+R9f+Rpqe9tVM4z1ml0lVAxvv1hyjY+kzwn0Mv6SsKTucSxcfSLZuJewOJnO2BFB54h+H5xIKVW135sx+ggl9vd1k9envKuzb3G+F95qNM9L8LfI/juzaqgnGwZjn4QuZob70qUJp61Xrh85lOpJ+JcS6zwZUztBK9RpnrcbEYMOns75qwCzAkbekHZt2PEUX0J3lujauvj4lPt9gGTiV9lVDmeI+XKf7u0pGDXwwdnGnUK6tlfXnA/i94wyMf/mcxLDsIDgid8SJbs0dsmCL8GP+943ScW0A3BnNiYQNtt4J2o38JV6ltoQR+MXORjnOyr0Lhb0U5XYNuMynUaYgKa1X22ndVkZVpbqWqfD+fOW2Lwnxc+noZV2dr+4Laevi7w5LttmajsHtjBZ6Wb2IP7QggkEEEcx9gOCJx5AIgs4hgywnh3ipWUGc+/lMEbH5GNz95ad5mKY4yvsYYIp8BhO8zkwbCD7OIQlsZ6TnH09D14dfbHOahFS1lU7A/itOubB/riae02VOm3HkHcb7es02rc+Ftn/vKNYw6zVajvU3n3whfWtv2PKJ2r2na22prQf+1xf6Rru3EXKW6a/+ng4GnbfaX3k4t0ndahTuc9PI/bp7c1rOLrFsBEpPhxFsx4TyjywzMB2nFt8oTCcCL8K/WM2TM4meI+kZgIXnEZkmcpddwVljCcn8VoOzLbUYIik43YnaHs3WVY40bI5MpDRbFOBYu84iF58Q84+tZTwtKeBrOPA5czKNKpAYYOZhgCMGf7TaquyytcfxU5n08jNHpe/s4c4wMx+x1K5rs+Rgp1dGc1NiJYGGRA2Jp33liZG3Od4Y75+wnwzi8ImZzYCEgA48uf2BQBk/IRrMDEz9ij7FQsZrriz8PRf3/FCaPXGk5GeBjuf9YNWfOLqgea5henh+Ga2urhdlG6qTtNDqS+B1neWD0idpausbWbfWdpWVvdkDxH4jnn9ZTaa7Aw6RLmIDjqILn843dEksgyesen9JzK3xGfkwlwz4h84TBuJcnCi+vOBthCZXtv5zj3ibbwuT9mIFXhzC5mYI1VDHL1hjO40fWkTWaPTiotWCCOmdsfidI1fEVdioPI8x8/SBLq/hII9D/rFNx6D6zuVx47APYzWaipamSsYB+p94GwwI6RO1W4cOgb1G01OtuJK/CJVp7rPhU+8/3Vfjms06NUnAxmcGEzJEzmVt4cGZIOJauPaVnpNZllXzzgwmDxERn5/tFO8d4DvA0HrOKD7BEKjOVz9ms1CopUHxH9vxVepdRjmJ96HkY2p8hHcscn7Kn2x9Ila2EZHKKy+cyf1Ry0D+cBwfOFa3/pP7R0ethn6+cz5RjkQvtKU3zGfwf/aWjB25Sk/F7RjEaFopgbEDZg4B8R+Qgtr6Vj5zKn+UD2mQIMmNp7CNnC/LMs7Ju5h1b9pdp7aj41x+PrsIwRONXmWEFs4gYGneYlVisvC24MsQ1nzU8jDObCZ8JnH4SJYcrNNzMatHG4+ctqNY8x0gVjBp7sZC59oWMVsQNFaBoCIp8oM+czL+7NFnHy4T9fx6mJsIGP28czAxES4Om/XmI9GHGDsT9I3ZdoAK21P7HH95YrpswIjNiKQBvPvGOkOsA/lz85Z3NihgW487qeQ+cRV84jKOSmNUtp8XGD67yzSvWfERjoR1mV6QQTAged40DFh/adoad/u2Qc4OWHp+PU4MWxfOd4n6hO8X1+kCsRyi6Zjudo6cPKGJZwtFbI5+xneMB7cxDYHXB3l9A6QbneYTBVsj1jFi2PKIXB5iIxxsMyxry2/0lWrbHxmUY1KcBf294NKMleRBwZZprU3xkeYnFBFgWKAJrNZ3dZUc2/HAZOJXpawNxkwUoOSiLQeu0wq8pVXnxGWWASxieQhqaFD5xLHQ+kS9W5HB/eM6f4T+3/SWKV2YjMOn7zlt6xLXW0hseBufXaVU0sMeIHzz/ePTdWfEPrBtvgj23lL1W4DEH1E12mReeA4xg9HB8pTY628LCWWWNfYVZsFvnK79Wp2Zv7y5iz5KAHrgYiiKFhyJaLBUzDoOsZ2Y5Jyfx1ThXBi2BvhMUqo35xr4vE7Y6R3OMDYThyZgDlHjmFjOJvLMDspB4RtNZdWLQx618S/OL2rXndcTV3AXZHWC4eRiWI+xJnAybqeIen+ksKuhcDcdR1ltycAYP0wy8x9Js64UjiTdd+Y8ol1+c8TQ6l2Azz8+US4nY5MKHoDMkRbiIziytk5EjEdGRiGGD+P0rhWOesLTiB6yhkXw9fOWkRb1XoZ98p6qwne6c+cY6f8AUfpHFH6/2lqCsY69YWHtNP8AdbqVQnxKkur8R4eUZWWzx9YnBBUjcmx7zu9Qm4GfVTBdvxHAbzVhk/KEuBa5VSDscDHONsrKBnhIwwldzdSRBaT/ADRS4i22/qMHeOIRjmIpWa1VNWSRkfD/AKfkOm+I+eIc5huaF4oLMB5xqcSzbaaOrityeS7y9i7ExhOz2BW6s9QDn2msr4cDzOfpF06avTqc4aWaW+r19xAWzuoHziWsu4Jz6SxjnjbAPoJlvhPUZI8vKLVirPEefymM82iKPMTxAekS0D+WLqE8jO9rYc/rNXc1b4XGMc+cZmY5Jz+QgkHMBDCFBCnrOz6vGzeQl5xLNpo1/wCHc/qbH0luBCGZsCVsK2GBnEubvHLHZQP+xNDqTRYB0Ms1NFmDxDhGc7zUle8wGyAOcVwOUGS2WPLkI2C+M7dZ3bN1+sWphzEXHlAuROGBRGtSsbiXWB2yFC+35FXVgZMLTvJxCaEgVOf6pqLMk4gXJmlQ/dc/1mXJvNMqizxEDY7mNbpVHPMe03Wjov8AKI+nyvrkTCnUsByPh+Y6zU6VairEbP8A3lT1L/IJY9Dry4T5iK/CPhzKrEPPadyeEshyOoi4M4WHwmcbZ3lTZ5cPzE1FBtrIGAfaMCDg8/yGhQWyekfeGEwzQj/h2/xS7aKPAPWUXvU+RyPMecs1Wmbrg+WJc+Ty2jZJgHCy+eZff3eCAeL+XPT194hKMCOhl/3VuGon19vKX9m93urbRG4GIZFljacKG4CpzyiUV2r4SJSzVW/pZTMZycbE9OUG04FI3E7kj4TFduonaQHEjdT+Q12cMyDGIELQcpTfYmcHbylrsxjV4EZQqkmUJnLmFJUha4L05n5SmgF+JvhG7GWWG60t9B6R68Nj0g4klGvPAUIyPXpODjYsPpBlFB5jqItCP4qzuOnUe01FjOw4huBji85TayGd5SRkriB6ujQmrzms1ar4UzxecZ2Y5JJ/JFXJjH0h2GIoy6+4jDJmot7w4Xlnb1iU4UARDxPZ6SkcD8XoZfYzYHJfL1lPxES2o8U4BwnMUYfEpfz5iPXlGHptKiVYS6sNXxeXP2M4SJUYycMIL1MAd+n5LpOzWs8T7L+81VH8QVUp8I3j6YVsoJy2MnyjbmaaviuH9O81eqDZVPh8/OaceOuX6jhoVF+Ijf0mgG1g9oybR1gJFoxGryssX+F7mW18ppWBJVusPEgx67GPWOY5GUMvEFbkwnBwsUPSY4TG5RTwtL04bXHr+R6DQjZ3ELgTiz7S1+K1z8oxAhJj7CBP4dZ9Iw3mhOLsfqBjrNScbdZVtZmUnw4PWMuWHkI6g4YcoayrSvUgDFg284qqQeE5EtQYUE43jfxFTOOIDGfONUYmy4aWmgc3Alz8dhb8i0FPeahQeQ3+kJCrLLgcAec1OsCLwru39oWP2KOXvLeco8WnX0yJaAnOV28NqN5Gfels4uAHbzjLzMCTvCQvksvvyCq8upmjbK8B+UdNo9fglTES8MyZyTiLdYvJjPvuo/VE7TvA8WG95qdR3zhuHG2PyPRXd1cD5jEZzY3pNTbwZ84Tk/avxqJYu8SyxdgxEbnAJoz/ABCvmI6bS7Fa/wBR5TSt4uE9Y9WGleRv5SuwW1569RNicStYgIPoY4wxHkfyem8Mu23nNZ8Y/wDAGwwMZwx2EUeKFJtyEVirAjnmNrqwvhUk/wBprdOwrrc88YY+sK7SmwWAK3xdPWJVgxAUsmhq470Xzb9pquxqGJarwHy/l/6RuzdSP/TJ9t52jQar8EYyob6/k9VpQzUsrBWB+xK3c4UZi9ntjxNiCipdgollYK4EWiwn4Y9B7nmcysbw6Q92Sdttv+sRDseZzsJ3d9icNgIE7ko5Ro1RBnZVQOmbvAG4z19No/ZyCzxZKsCFbqD0zOxtK1dtjWDGPCPnzl5RMsX2jduaUZ/ifQTW6vR6qhybBxKPDnY/lOk0wY5cbdIh4fh29pkmGEzjjagDpDdw28a7RtUHqM01pWzIHKJqK7OHLb+s1NPEd/lE0xcqMiVItY4eJDjbwnM40YnAO3nK+eTO26dVbSOBAVG5wd/yrS095ZjoBk/ZgT5widYmmHDxNsJein4RLdM2DlhMcImk4gpYS0hkzKrHz8R+s4iDBZjdTKO8BznOYrtvtEXPWa7sei9SFVUbOeLE7Q0g02oNYbiGAc/lHZ5YWkjou8PigE4YEg7uscRHEfLpLLbHbJnFNYGNnygozX6zRf8Akn3li4PvOEDBgK/KIWJ2iXW92oAGxgtZt8Qtqek1/aN9BAPMy2x7HLMck/lGhGFdvPAg+zP2HJ6xgMD2hE7vJhHA5HkZQFFjDo6zcnPlNigIhI+GUswxgZgvsUjwbQajngzUa2xF+L5R3Z2yxyfyns0DumPm0IEIh295mPgAseQlepS338oTA01QIfPnEsK7npyiNleJhzmeFSZWAWEQcODwEiNqMjdcS/V8J2j2u/M/lXZJJ416bGH7DL7FqGW68h5zUap7fRegldjI2RKr1s9D5SpeYmqqOPaNpi+ntbyGYtxapV6RvEfQSnwxdQ/SV+P4pZodO+CwlnY9LZ7t2B9eUv0Gpq+JNvMbj8p7JP8AFs/wf5/Y7qBljgS7tHpWPmYUuc5OT7z7sf1CdyPOdxnkZojfWx24gRLtYA2GUcpzB8iImnrFIPHviBVB2gimVttmVnwxTFnbWhrFXfKMEHf1/KOyBvafQRuvpNbX3gG/LlE06Jv1jGEThiSgia+0tqF8K7couqxpz4Bk+UB4piYijaIdsRTFbaAzuldcMMg8xO1uzhpbFKnwPnA6jH4T/8QAKxABAAIBBAIBAwQDAQEBAAAAAQARITFBUWFxgZGhscEQQFDR4fDxMCCA/9oACAEBAAE/EP8A9elqgC7Ll4AicaH1OT+UNi1aPcprDNKvm+41hRiHHCGmd7hIAdEA/aXgtvJ7cR6LB/tg9SgwGMx62gMFNlwpBHcW3G4AiGg3WP0v+B3rd0IRozF+1bnn5hRI/wBDMP8A5FhW0LW9i4e4sc2X5E3jXnd0Ph3g0O7kLdN5S8FWv8DkgorWnPk7gDVAtTCQEEAoDYI2CP1SG4RjtAHbn8wQSdpg8H9yrEbuoYBj+AoZnV6DuB0qAHmmrXyEHF4FM8cBmFCesfOM8jUZBam73g/6/wDDDu/UXVRqLKyXX1tAltjlckNB2HDBTXS2oGEwadh7mYZz7YlXghg3zfiNRoFbrL14mrKm6awxV5/ZBiOhsafgD1Le4Gyigaq0CXhdF79hpKsDZYaJ1++2hC2DdXB7issCha5UM3KP3hh3yRNHJA5OMbXonhyS68YC1tVzLqdj2oQ+Y9RhClev6IA1UD3L4rzVY9VAKydKUfvK1CuNCx41IJR0ETfpld7nuCUckeh2jogUY0L6YgU0S/0x6x4bDT7osHq/mNKmrFEJepW1QtDm2ZJCMjuXxEwWtdnDgz95qAnkqWfuwyC2KDmJv0BBFss3xpDABgqU8VCiDxzGgYMBoncfUMK7bh4mdorg75sHbgZjkdbX0H7R8gUhSPY/pcOEfiZGyH0h3njqY1XTYxT1S6Of7RJYO4aPZEF9LZOHf5hU8RyJj+JcJrZ6YszJ6mU5aIFnYx8S+pVwirxR5goDjLHLKIgU1UPbFFnP1iM2UVQFcPctMUB/Hr90xyryg2KcPMe7kmIuhNQnDHNEMm3YiYHos0nSEWC0IfU+yoksTgPqqj4IZf8AY3huoR1qMZeAgvT+tyvIU+pi0lSfZPAFy67rHUPeHfvZmYvWo4SleSaTyPpCFqexiovK8EsNiDojSaQGEoaHEsL+J0wZ48RRluCCDtYwcroREVtW17f3IK0RfgGCDeC3RxtCVsIEOGs1AVAOEsR5HaFh5gp9zJgEsvh4jugKjoKLiCBVsSn8wy7cfnaJk0UZk2pv1xETCsVqnB3L0lrR39ZIvhLlqzyJAiWbxVjSet/cvnQmBGWyzJiXKvaH1RNUVIhA7qr+B1BhvXf9WKA1rLLLmfeLvrAAgEKt9Er8Rtyrc07cfuqWWWXmObAC604exzuRZZbuVYXtLqqXrpHqcFXBi4e9XPC7VAII050lY0mi0+G5iOsSSLZq1PMSalRz61k5JSvKEYNQYfkghdDh1jOuGYka6+YI+B+ZvS4UWuIKbzYDskxHcpYgC1WPEdA0zEBWhHFmrcDXHdy4C2C071xFaYgo+Zg8NWrpxQwTHp2fmLc8bWW7Xf8AcmABQgDwHVTHbJLD0ZHjMdD5AfeFBP3LH4Ju9Gra8rrYj3ssVWpUpLIFazyMAAbFa1Fci92D5YZCbxb/AFBZF1xpTFZmyXGG5cx8RL7lildr/sBWavpLxtnUjSCwuxrEQxxE851gqjQKi6L6DSK9CUkyyvUcXxX6AN52+JuiGMpT6hVhdS98NeDu98furk6BdPEW2PcX+yWY/r9Bz7NrrchfYizvqCKGVtVR2/oiNaalhUObQO4N9Yz7G0rLroMg6YDDHmjT+pYhhhe2SMt6PyQ7rW0uWNHNw8sQocQgy6xrW/0g8oqo1lUyPshSvLav0SaUU9vyv6K3QQiPOrkPEBahc3afm4AEto6j4T98KNkddo6fciQXC6MdzZOWIPyfoG5kmFWivn8My5teHp7l6sbJQh99zFOSF73fxPJmYr6j7yoZKwMJLqomF/ZtKkDuW6QHZ+DM0GTzKGP0RuYpd1mDKp2o1adZShqDwMfX9+o0bxggq7u0ERRio2S2+YhMMds+JXBYKSORQluqHfsl39LpFXqZiS94T7cxE1LZqgNiu40F0i4ofWMg1gBI4tb4qG1foh93Obt9VLI9mpHwwRnM6AdRsoe2fGC4BrHMAQA19StILUNeMhf60df34CuzOGPOJghwK8KDGwPOIQJT6sDAVHGsvDrKMpWvB/iF8XXpd+JjgOGBVadOYghU8QvCxKGadMnHiJQBkN7NywXHFTO2ti6+stI00014hx4qXJW1MsddkYKG/cu7KB2QZt4zTyQVa1F3ExmZmbKZA6cL++cBqtQT2y/1NAfoisgHjMSYF87wcWzY57mpOYjVk3KENoGaCXcbSiaTTNCAVvwFv0Z+yPmAZI4OT0lsZr7FjqPEqVL3LBoxLhGHwkbqY3FPpmEDWzZIvmK9DBCuf+SpFTJWFOSZukFrQrRXLUIq2/8AWbihC0UF5rb1LXOI6toBsMcyi+7A3BrGbk3f3zpLCEjbe0vSHlxLtBZSprdXEwBRghhGu8T17McTibGXNU8iasMNDnDcyIAJV50Y3iEVNk2++IkAqq99wpjzbQYpjTOnplK8OXWnlZ+IlXWos5DWnn5lG1jY3m1rQd+4XqobUuKxdZNQjQgTAmmOYZYHaKTh2YEKHF3LI0E3lqkcRjEfzZi8FpHiBqP78SQA1eYAanzLoAV4Ys0FGd0Nm4fS16oyz6IjE+vxInY8/wBWK0+vCYMtTr4jnX8IX+1lcUGX0QsqwtOmNLgjUgpesSlrTxiBYV0s+SDMMO9D7JLw4ts8gsX4ZWk6sRVBo3YWoCl6Wb/7rHm0Zb1eZhs72uIiKPJOm+YskurbovMvUg/EcU44uUlNRu/l/AkxPB+Yha0SJM0xHiH3VSlRtDanuFSYb+dpsEvEMuBgUR2WnhiGzLemiDCgDfcMbampQhzjU7IGnsEUBtqolWoBqt8bCxs1LAaU59S6dlSjCH69wKsF4Bo+Yer+CDoRvqaXNQDN+HhhQISLz3BAizLQlyv8CYGowSpmsm85r+gtdkoPLDNGrEJzmMbr4Q/zADcNBlaCW8lZRpfEQ8pjfKUDuKLKAj3xBajOoxZVVrfUrxglMXed+ma0vxm/LAIgeh65mCN1JKt4Ool0hd0Kz5iuCA7vn/E0vTcgeJwCXwM6FXcpZqqhXt7/AIIS19jiJdkVeZdN4j9hFBk7sRFzU2VnR8GsXVFiLiSgvuKkOO1/9mA6FBKC9WuWOaGgO28Ew6WunBQPZDHJDelVtMfSUVfKxLb2c3pNyFcewuLOdt0s8SmpBYNlcn9QFVTXJ4YYmr4lA+AVm6BTQNeNPMXggaR2f4GolmVdxKzHOCBZoLly6wSp4me4X8xflCn0H9m0xluUr+kFgUYbYgsugF68zNsx4Dphy24mRKhfWYqzdbiJbAbvNR0FHslh/iA7UabMfJAMhRGROR5OI+sNYTUeziCEX41OeSLVAQlML2OInsc7kR6ET/cy5dxw6wuEiwFAjjWtH+BKwmF1JVsbnePER6h1O8JOaZWS+u5Y1tYdFaAHrE0egism9H6WgoryILYrUMs0r/MVJQtcGz3KrllAnJDuEErJXIxF9FC1vRUqQFafTph14yN68zclRmYGp2XsgVGzcdGByLbmn0hSqDiWxwdcRiyoFwqn8y4M5W/4TxBrDaAGwBDX/q4wN0vlhJKPS07NL8QD2AhMMhA7u7+0C0LXyJK/wI035P4nxonqXDXBMkGqNNrxctli9GM8EpdmcLqfTMSNadHSCCZXp/Qy71EGnI6kZY0jwglo5NvcVW1Vef4Qss2jd/UvQ1YzS3OXxCQtYNBsECkJKlZL0xuvEIS21Wo4xtDydP5hNM+/BXHlhPQX3lD5cTKxgC01RvcqWtqfJiU03A+MxqwyDc2IIX2QXGQDwcjAUX4HibpgeeT+o8ykH7MHEWeEjG9wjdB14c/wdbIOQdDzMeaH0mAMCt4/1ZdFDdC9AxC9beoi6ssrzDQdRArTVEiKWDc2Xsz+JZXRAINX0Iglywi5upeYHEP+sPyECPUcVptLGH2J5lTLmzkiLgHTFQfkkbX2Sjk9xhhXnjmbiuz+IYRhceiv4IAFgs6jW1YthN29VlQEgmvA77ilXf8AS5PMKT3foGaszxvEVNNo43gYdpQ+kTJleYrtDE9Qxu7w9ZPZ0dQU7n8yYzWjTL0VrZ9JQopMb3IttOSacvr94AUV9EEAqKvBo8QqAy4G7r+DNTRH7m9KuDl5jaGWAiIrauX9fmiNeWAhbQauFWqvbLYJ/wBSSwAZYq+xhx3BFp6Xv/MRiLAw5D3EAAJ7OTqOAprfuWWJm5S0sKR3J20Hx/DmXUPRjHIuP/gqDRGMrqrKzB8kdXEEOo7xEsLQooTRweTv6gOX7kyetpYEigYYT9HmAt818xUCnD1KpNC98Mv0lTTt7143j6yKj6Q4tPCVSM/w9jMm5zCZOo8nn9CKVwEzgrgLhhgt0tfMXkF9by4Csd8EZbm0FD1FcTmXXVoHMXgMADKsDVrasxBmTR5HRPMIFbx9tOzUgo39mEyjcaWX2ae4uRhtzbqHVaSlIGVXBNwqaFG+5dAVobDY5v8AiWD8MHRlFKB4VGxe8AEXaNHNMNpSS/FC6feGIVdS+xOEfoh0MFuM2uhsan+JqiktcV5h5NBTA+Jmz0bM9EA7QMwuYN0euD+Kp2ZHgIANadQswxQi6VdI5KbS7+IfVXKwi0As5jRyZdmIgwP6JAJWWFWqNHa+4DGilJ/Uw8DUMPRBesYl4G0WkcDLu+bjwwIinPj+IShBE8l6PuK1uJh1lVq/pL2iAud0DQ9y868GwdQD0x2bACWFaM+ZSncD6hYHlUwDOIzKXSYnsDeIIqXz1BtzcjKxDZNY2SkpnHuKOVa/xDoVVXOcNuJiZJT3UcqNWLRQ3zNPgb52mA/62gpK2OtTlCBl1iHD/wBi4ZKVMyFpk8QTTTeM5zc6jQkRkWAtO7wMWozDCxiar/EhQl06XoQWhE2gBXs/iUbmgc7X8eWKqY5NiVMsqtamANH2hF29h1pL+lQFh4ji225iVwByajCqZbRmBSmk17Tjb+KRuwoPOISUBfwQnuDVTUGvh/cSBwaOnl5YDfJ9Zj7KNXPUBdyJNGVcIBTNgRgRVhwEeF7Qwixt4hU3sv5lOFhVjTXdSgAc0bp51hqo/wC8rT+JY4P6IhVuhERd5cBFFD0WfR/cpAzuv7iNXlNC2pU5+mD/ACSW6KCt/rKriJc5lOS38XdlRWZNhCFNPrEG8oiA0CQFDNzurmeriU1iFcUd05Of4g3eA/LBWWgz2y0KNjYldS+TElkpcAQjpkjo3rUXo7wsFRqlBfEcK4ylGkQ4rxmGj+5Rl94NUKPcqQ4h4JowsYlqQOQsR2l8Ow3kDycP7T//xAAwEQACAgEDAwIEBgIDAQAAAAABAgARAxIhMQRBUUBhBTCBkRATInGxwUKhICNg0f/aAAgBAgEBPwD/ANUGUmgfSaxdcH/iSAIMqkzNlIcAGfmGZcpK155iORxMBbVZM/PW69DmYAAm6vgTqs/Tr0+R+6qTX+W2/efCPi2Pq8b77pyTtY8n+4Ot6YsqjKpJNCje/wBPwOZb7zLkFgXtDYND6QkarjeRH3MC7Q2BQigA2ZjzEtR+eTQM6/qM6ZNeNyVA3Q7j7T4r8Qx5unH6CrLxW4nwXp8ahxkU0zA1/ia3F3+8wk6QAo09tNUPw1EE39YpBP0l2sbmIbsHxGl0oi2SY1CExWYEVzBdD5vVu64yVXUfHFzP16MDaMD9/wD5MaYsuYgg0faFeo6c6TjVlXxsf7nRdSmXIoUZBQJI7TNkdWHiZCj78N/MW1IuNzYl3BsfpBCbmrxKuEgTEyhrMXPjJq/m5E1KRZF9xM3QZyTao3uBOl+E5FcM77XekTq8IZQ1cfxBlx4gAiDcbmZc7OK97gMo15Evad4xveXtNW0Bg5lDzCO0w4hdsa9pfoOpQIa+37QGXEcgw1yOIyMvIMuKVqpQJ9ocYIFGEEbHaAwNUJBHvOmBCb+fnk0Jny4nPDbd5pXwfvAgqzKitUDbcwpvFQh2s9hXiUb4mg0SDCwKixZG37iMFqxY9jKgBsDvMWPQtXZ+eyggg95lx/luR9ou53m2rcw6TwRCp8j7iDYz/LnYntGUUP5ij2uKBccUu0LG+TOeLgcqZhy61uq9D1iHWGvn+vw0/puJzfiC7imyD4lAjn6TT3qAiM9/vN4GYTAus2y2B3gAHoHcKpY9o+RnayYI10B7RCATfipVEHmA0PcxRtzHB7HYfWXfJ/qHbkbHuJUph7zpcv6tPn0LorrR4i9EgaySR4nUsiLoUUTzXiAk1CIQYGU1cLm5r2vvO9wtamtvMDkbTWSQKEx4lQcb9z6JVsWdhOrxBba7Zj44ETG2ktWwl7X7zVZAhFRaO3tGgMGxuMu+3E0Xx9ol6FvmhfoVqxfEyOaocXUZVarANTrD/wBYHk/xFrTFNbxiTvN5rNxwKiZCrA+DPy8Z30j7QY0BsDf0bE2t+fwdEYixdTNh0uAoNEfvGxslahBjYDcTMV1WvExqXbSOYmJjkCkEb0Zl6TExsWv7cRBSgeAB6XmBRMjhRzBky6gdBFQ2x2mQA7EXcxY0xkneYwKsjeEEG+3pbqVALmin33PmZL2EQ7j3jMDZitqbVdDtFcA8/wCoDqPLelEI7TYbTfvMpNfWLkrJV7gzIxLafvFJEUFms8RSK29Kh3+hhOkXLMJMJYg7/wCp1ZewwNknkbTE36idJu/MJJ7RL2iGFTV9vl//xAA5EQACAQIFAQYEBAUDBQAAAAABAgMAEQQFEiExQQYiUWFxgRNAkaEwMkKxEBQjUtEgYsFDYHJzsv/aAAgBAwEBPwD/ALqmy/GQwpLJC6IxsrEWB+UKm1+n+nC4WbETJFEup24HpvWM7J5ph4fiFFcdQhJI9rV2NyGCTBTTYiAMXfSodb2C9RfxNHstliIAYAyi+/Dc35FZZ2NwsOZCfVriQXVG373T1ArNsqix+H+DIxCl1bbyPHvXbDA4ODKI4ooEDGVVjCrvc/ve1R9hMxOFaR3RH03EfJ9CenyOFwkWGwccjQo8km/ett7Gp8Q7NZo1C+Fv2NTR6W8jV9qAJNhUfYnNWj1FoVNvyljf7A12TyFsPHLJPDpnEhVWP9th+X1vS7jf3/zSqdNvvUaE91hvvUcQVAPCgbtv0NSYSGSWOSRQTGSUv0J2vWKSV4XWNgrstg3Nr9fas87H5fhMrkljdw8YB1Mb6ulredHY7/jYWL4k8aXtqYC9ZkTJITqY6QBz99rc1cC4LXHnyKxJDMN9vChSsQQRyKw08eIgilXh0DD3F6kUhdtt+lIpDb9fvQ2UURuDR3pRzTX9qAvvRUHp9azCLCnDSGdVMQUlrjoOamdGldlXSpYkL4Anj8XJtKidwoaRVGkHwPJp8Uz7ta/0rFSRsTa4NENc8GgtlvXZbKsqzDBSxyR3mVtzcg2PBFZRk+Ky/wDprOZIOiPyv/ifDyobixpNQXetVKwovSmwvSi+53om1Hiu0uWY3H4P4MEqpdgXB/UB51jexWZ4eF5SY3VFLHSTew9vxYpXjcMpsRQzBWHeUX8tqlmDNcAVFoLgMNiaybsimMBlkmKxarKq/mPueKyvs5gMvmMsIfUU0nU17gm//FBquL77VxV7NtTDSvpWvu38aMgABqOTa9CRTQYn9J+1MBYg/wCK7TYzMhh3iwmGkYspDSC1gD4DkmpYpI3KOjKw5VhYj6/IdisbOySxkXjFiSejeXrSv4GhJvRe4seK1EL4io50dTY7+ex+9F9Vxelkgjis7gj0pRrc2uFBsL06OB3T7UjEAdKRjVxRNdu5w+ZooQjREO8f1XP7D8dVZmCqCSTYAck12fyTOMHEQWgVWOoqbswNvKwpcNjj/wBaID/1m/8A9UkQ21G9uTxTg/pFLKU2YG37UZEtfYjxqZWBuov5eNStNinvCSEB3B2N16VhpWiBBLjx1b2+t61yRHWsusNvZjz6GosSrEMFO5II6gilLX6WpAanmSGJ5GBIVSTYXO3hWf50+ZYv4mnTGosi9QPE+Z/Hw88kE0cqGzIwYddxWRZsuNwSzHSG3DKDexH+aWUSC4YEeRrUotejLGwsDUyE7hwKnBjHekN/b/msfj8VDCsselgw3Xr9qwuOxL4mbcINZsrcimlktdlN/wC5Rf62vWNnfT3Ts3JsdiAe941l2J1z2Z2RgN9NwpI2+1ueKglvuG1ClNxxUqLJGyPuGBB9DWe5UMvxzQiQOtgynrY9D5/I9isZG+CfDgaXjYsT/cG6+vSmMlYZB8Is3N60h8So53v9N6zBBY7amNYqJBlwhY/1NVr72AJud/IVDFg8XCJG7k4XS7BtJuB1HBFDEMkrIJfykjUbX9rVNrIBsRdrAE7nxJHnWHy8qVUR9yw5JPvzWGhCrZRagziu2OdmDDiGHEBJiRcITrA9RxTuzsWZiSeSTcn5DA4STFYqOFOXa1/AdT7VhMFh8Hh1ihXSo5PVj4mmxLL50kl8Mp4Ft6jAjKNbnc+9Tywrd1ZWIPHO/nWLxU2JdQQFiRgT01WNZlJAk0aquwdWkNvAbfUHely1lkMkMcbAniwDA9dzTR6v6gMakbG43Ht41h42QKCVa/B4pUFhcWPlWhhz3h967cZPE+H/AJ1CQ0YVWU8FSbC3mCfkcFjZsLOssRAZfEXG9T9scY8GlYkR+rjf6A12fgxmJnGLnkLopIXUSbt4geVS6hGEufMVimSNSf1WsooQLGkaHdmJv5m1zXwFiiJK6m1XA8qTCfGhLnvMX7x96SObCyKEbuMeD0vUcYaIsOTc+53r4WpL2tY7ioSRsanmeOJ2CliqkhRybdBWcZ1iswnZnZgl+5HfZR09/P5IsBt1rsvjZJ5o4VULDChPNyzE9fresRmeFjxUcOoPKTcqN7W338KieSTEEtuVUfvxSMTi0ZuAbDyvtWJRQhJ4FZUukSXOzMTbwqbDiQEHwt9Kw5CJpc2I6/5pwAhItY+dBTpFxvU8scaa3dVA6sQB96xvwv5uf4ZvH8RtB/232+RJPSgu9Q4meEMI5GQNzY2vauykQbHM5/Sth6sbVHOYcSzFSQwI2qaV3cWGkA3A9KiYzQgsbkXB9aJWOZY77tyfA9KQuJtTc8e1OEZbjgisRg/5jBSQm9nQrfwJ4NDNc0hvGMXOoUkFRIbC3vWIzrMZ8P8AAlnZ47g2ax48+fk7b/wwuOxGH1fCfTqIuQN9qybOlxEEj4mVA6vckkKNJ4tUGdYTFvIMOT3DYs21weo8qPabDwLMIplOnnrc/wC3xrstmf8ANiSGVry6ma56hjf7GszzgZfhRLKmuzqo3sTfn3tWL7S5emCmkilBPwdUd9rl7qNvIjcdKy7tdmmFTRdJkHAkuSPQgj71iJmmmklYAF3ZiBx3jf5XWavViTUbBTz60wUKQKgmlhkWSNyrqbgjkVmOd47GpGuIfWEvbYDc9TbrQNAj5U8VpFWFHYUpsaVr3H8DRY0gv8qTYXrV1oEk1pFqIIpX3HrW+9EigRfegy9PlW/Ka5O/FagOBWsmixoqQAaLnqeaIHj/AAU0huPw/wD/2Q=="
        style="width: 300px; height: 200px" src="">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function htmlToXml(html) {
      var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
      var text = html.innerHTML;
      doc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns', doc.documentElement.namespaceURI);
      doc.documentElement.innerHTML = text;
      let htmls = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc.documentElement);
      return htmls;
    }

    function getImage(element) {
      var htmlElement = element;
      var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvasElement.height = 800;
      canvasElement.width = 500;
      var canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="800" crossorigin="anonymous">' +
        '<foreignObject width="500" height="800">' +
        htmlToXml(htmlElement) +
        '</foreignObject>' +
        '</svg>';

      var url = '';
      var DOMURL = window.URL;
      var svg = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });
      url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

      var img = new Image();
      img.setAttribute('width', '500');
      img.setAttribute('height', '800');
      img.onload = function() {
        canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var res = canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png');
        console.log(res);
      }
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.src = url;
    }

    var htmlElement1 = document.getElementById('content1');
    var htmlElement2 = document.getElementById('content2');

    getImage(htmlElement1);

    getImage(htmlElement2);
  </script>
</html>
```

Run it in **Edge** and observe the output in the console. The base64 images of both the HTML elements are logged separately. The base64 for **content1** is generated properly while that for **content2** contains a blank image.

Answer (score 0):

Loading an image is an asynchronous task, even when the `src` is set to a dataURL.

I guess Edge's young integration of <foreignObject> still has some quirks for delaying the outside's <img> `onload` event until all its inner resources are effectively loaded.

I don't think there is much you can do here, apart from filling an issue, or adding a delay inside the <img>'s `onload` event handler.

You may want to try [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) but I'm not even sure Edge supports this, nor if it may work at all.

And for your more general case, you may want to avoid this foreignObject hack altogether and rather draw your DOM directly from the canvas API, just like [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/) does.